# Readers and writers in postgres- concurrency

Tags: postgresql

The PostgresSQL says:

> Readers don't block writers and writers don't block users.

Let's assume SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

Great! But, how is it possible?

1. Reader doesn't see changes commited made by a writer after reader's snapshot was taken.
2. Therefore a Reader needn't to be blocked during its transaction because he has own snapshot.
3. But.... is taking a snapshot blocking? It seems that it must be blocking because, otherwise, snapshot can be inconssitent if any writer commit changes during making a snapshot.
4. So, does it mean that:

   > Readers don't block writers and writers don't block users.

...but taking a snaphot blocks.

?

Please explain me that :)

Comment: [How Postgres Makes Transactions Atomic](https://brandur.org/postgres-atomicity) is probably worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses [multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (MVCC) to handle concurrency. Simply put, it means that an `UPDATE` doesn't actually modify the existing data, but instead marks it as "deleted", tags it with the current transaction ID, and creates an entirely new record. The previous version is still there, and still visible to anyone who needs it.

So "taking a snapshot" doesn't actually involve copying any data; it's more or less just a matter of recording the IDs of all uncommitted transactions at that point in time, so that the server can filter out their effects while scanning a table.

For a much more thorough explanation, check out Bruce Momjian's [MVCC Unmasked](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/mvcc.pdf).